# [NetworkManager]dconf-WARNING

Tags: networkmanager, dconf

Each time I would like to add a new connection (Ethernet, Vpn...) to NetworkManager I have this error :

```
(nm-connection-editor:3580): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Erreur lors de la génération de la ligne de commande « dbus-launch --autolaunch=d2f5ef2f9aba40c791161299cacbd9d1 --binary-syntax --close-stderr »`
```

I'm completely lost, any help please.